# Light bulb socket adapted to a 3 pin plug socket

Tags: electrical

In my loft i have a light bulb operated by an on off switch. Is there a gadget that screws into the bulb holder that would turn it into a 3 pin plug holder? I need a power source for a squirrel repellent plug.

Answer (score 2):

Hire a handyperson to do this.  Or at least, turn off all power before doing any work, and get up to speed with electrical safety by reading a decent book on DIY home electrical.

The fixture almost certainly is attached to an octagon box.

Remove light fixture entirely.  Then install any common receptacle in this style of octagon box cover

[image]

and fit it up to the light's junction box.

If you run a ground *wire* to the receptacle, then you can mount the recep to the plate with just 1 screw (the middle screw).  You need the 2 outer screws if grounding is coming through hard metal-metal contact between plate and box.

If your octagon box is 1/2" too small for this type of plate, then you have a "3-1/2" size box, and that will require a very special plate that has (and includes) only 1 socket.

Comment: Perhaps some safety advise would be helpful in order to avoid electrocution.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Normally that would make answers unduly weighty... but you're right, OP has given no indication of being ready for a foray inside a junction box.

Comment: The OP has also given little indication of where in the world they are. This is an america-centric answer, but I was under the impression that "plug socket" was more of a british term.